# How to calculate difference in date in snowflake?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have these two days:

```
BEFORE_DATETIME: 2021-09-02 09:41:00
AFTER_DATETIME: 2021-09-09 09:41:00
```

I need to calculate the difference in these two days. So in this example: 7 days.However, in the BEFORE_DATETIME, I have some values that are string (bad records). I keep getting an error when I use DATEDIFF function because of those records.

How can I calculate the difference in date and to ignore the bad records?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_timestamp.html) function which will parse your input as a timestamp and returns **NULL** if parse fails.

Then you can apply your **DATEDIFF** as you please.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT
     $1 AS before_datetime,
     $2 AS after_datetime
  FROM VALUES
  ('2021-09-02 09:41:00', '2021-09-09 09:41:00'),
  ('random_bad_record', '2021-09-09 09:41:00'),
  ('2021-09-02 09:41:00', 'random_bad_record')
)
SELECT
    TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(before_datetime) as before_datetime,
    TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(after_datetime) as after_datetime,
    DATEDIFF('days', TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(before_datetime), TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP(after_datetime)) AS diff_in_days
FROM cte
;
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you so much! I think this could work, but I have the two columns of values (thousands of records) would I need to input each one under "FROM VALUES"?

Comment: Of course not, the FROM VALUE is just here to reproduce your use-case in a single readable query.

From your side you just have to use the final query. I updated it in order to use TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP in the final query and make it more reusable for you.

Comment: Apologies, you're right! It works, thank you so much! Really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add to the discussion here about this point:

> I have some values that are string (bad records).

I've seen date/time data that's inconsistent - pulled from various sources or typed in by a person in different formats. If you have "bad" dates like that, this SQL UDF comes in handy. It will try various common date and time formats before finally trying the base TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP. If none of them work it will return NULL.

It has a better chance at converting dates in string fields if they have inconsistent formats, but should ***only*** be used in that situation since it adds overhead to the conversion. You can see how the pattern works and add your own parser to the list of attempts.

```
create or replace function TRY_MULTI_TIMESTAMP(STR string)
returns timestamp
language SQL
as
$$
    case
        when STR RLIKE '[A-Za-z]{3} \\d{2} \\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2}' then try_to_timestamp(left(STR, 20), 'MON DD YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        when STR RLIKE '\\d{1,4}-\\d{1,2}-\\d{2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} [A|P][M]' then try_to_timestamp(STR, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH12:MI:SS AM')
        when STR RLIKE '\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{4}' then try_to_timestamp(STR, 'mm/dd/yyyy')
        when STR RLIKE '\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} [A-Za-z]{2}' then try_to_timestamp(STR, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH12:MI:SS AM')
        when STR RLIKE '\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{1,2}\\/\\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}' then try_to_timestamp(STR, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI')
        when STR RLIKE '[A-Za-z]{3}, \\d{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3} \\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2}:\\d{1,2} [A-Za-z]{3}' then try_to_timestamp(left(STR, len(STR) - 4) || ' ' || '00:00', 'DY, DD MON YYYY HH:MI:SS TZH:TZM')   -- From Snowflake "LIST" command
        when STR RLIKE '\\d{1,2}/\\d{1,2}/\\d{2} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2} [A|P][M]' then try_to_timestamp(STR, 'MM/DD/YY HH12:MI AM')
        when STR RLIKE '[A-Za-z]{3} [A-Za-z]{3} \\d{2} \\d{4} \\d{1,2}:\\d{2}:\\d{2} GMT.*' then try_to_timestamp(left(replace(substr(STR, 5), 'GMT', ''), 26), 'MON DD YYYY HH:MI:SS TZHTZM')  -- Javascript
        else try_to_timestamp(STR) -- Final try without format specifier.
    end
$$;

select try_multi_timestamp('Sat Oct 02 2021 17:53:40 GMT+0000 (Coordinated Universal Time)'); -- JavaScript date format
select try_multi_timestamp('Fri, 17 Apr 2020 17:55:45 GMT'); -- Snowflake LIST command file time
select try_multi_timestamp('Oct 26 2021 6:25:15');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [TRY_TO_DATE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_date.html) and the value "fails to parse" you will get null,
thus you can feed the result of that TRY into the DATEDIFF or you can use an inline IFF you skip that thus something like:

```
IFF(TRY_TO_DATE(before_datetime) IS NOT NULL AND TRY_TO_DATE(after_datetime) IS NOT NULL, 
    DATEDIFF('days', before_datetime, after_datetime),
    0) AS alias_name
```

replacing `0` with what you want when the values are bad. etc